Shortcuts for auto indentation not working
I want to use the command Reindent Selected Lines or Reindent Lines with a shortcut. I tried setting keybindings to each of them but when I press them in notebooks or scripts (using Python), nothing happens and the indentation is not corrected.
I know there is the Format Selection command but that changes the code too much for my liking. I only want to have things properly aligned/indented.
How can I make this shortcut work in notebook cells and scripts?

Troubleshooting information:
Here is how the shortcuts look like:

Here is the code I am trying the shortcuts on:
for n in range(10):
    for r, l in zip([results1, results2],
                         ['test', 'test2']):
        a = [[1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6]]
        print(n, l, r)

Here is the output from "Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting" when pressing Ctrl+Shift+Tab:
2024-10-23 16:55:13.548 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.
2024-10-23 16:55:36.838 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2024-10-23 16:55:36.840 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2024-10-23 16:55:36.841 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
2024-10-23 16:55:36.841 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
2024-10-23 16:55:36.842 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2024-10-23 16:55:36.857 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2024-10-23 16:55:36.858 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2024-10-23 16:55:36.859 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 16, key: Shift
2024-10-23 16:55:36.860 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 4 ('Shift')
2024-10-23 16:55:36.860 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2024-10-23 16:55:36.916 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2024-10-23 16:55:36.917 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+shift+Tab
2024-10-23 16:55:36.918 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 1 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.reindentselectedlines, when: no when condition, source: user.
2024-10-23 16:55:36.919 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: Tab, keyCode: 9, key: Tab
2024-10-23 16:55:36.919 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: Tab, keyCode: 2 ('Tab')
2024-10-23 16:55:36.920 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+shift+Tab
2024-10-23 16:55:36.920 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 1 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.reindentselectedlines, when: no when condition, source: user.
2024-10-23 16:55:36.921 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Invoking command editor.action.reindentselectedlines.
2024-10-23 16:55:37.442 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier shift due to it being pressed together with other keys.

Here is the output from "Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting" when pressing Alt+I:
2024-10-23 16:55:59.186 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2024-10-23 16:55:59.201 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2024-10-23 16:55:59.201 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [alt], code: AltLeft, keyCode: 18, key: Alt
2024-10-23 16:55:59.202 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [alt], code: AltLeft, keyCode: 6 ('Alt')
2024-10-23 16:55:59.202 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2024-10-23 16:55:59.346 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2024-10-23 16:55:59.346 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving alt+I
2024-10-23 16:55:59.347 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 1 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.reindentlines, when: no when condition, source: user.
2024-10-23 16:55:59.347 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [alt], code: KeyI, keyCode: 73, key: i
2024-10-23 16:55:59.348 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [alt], code: KeyI, keyCode: 39 ('I')
2024-10-23 16:55:59.348 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving alt+I
2024-10-23 16:55:59.348 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 1 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.reindentlines, when: no when condition, source: user.
2024-10-23 16:55:59.349 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Invoking command editor.action.reindentlines.
2024-10-23 16:55:59.690 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier alt due to it being pressed together with other keys.

Here is the file I get from Developer: Inspect Key Mappings:
Layout info:
{
    "name": "00000816",
    "id": "",
    "text": "Portuguese"
}

Default Resolved Keybindings (unique only):
(...)
                     ctrl+shift+Tab =>                      ctrl+shift+Tab
(...)
                     ctrl+shift+tab =>                      ctrl+shift+Tab
                              alt+i =>                               alt+I


What do you see when you troubleshoot your keybindings? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post. Include also the top section of the file opened by running Developer: Inspect Key Mappings in the command palette and all following text that is related to the keys of interest.

@starball thanks for the help, added the info now

it looks like the commands are correctly bound. do you just not have a formatting provider for the programming language you're writing in or something? sorry, I'm not super familiar with the reindent lines feature.

I am a bit of a noob wrt to VS Code. I did install the Black Formatter [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.black-formatter] for Python so I do have a general formatter and the Format Selection shortcut works fine, but changes the code structure too aggressively for me
